# file not found - how to remove its configuration?

Tags: oracle, rdbms, tablespaces, datafile

I run oracle 10.2.0.5.

I have the following:

```
SQL> select file#, status, error, recover, tablespace_name, name
  2  from v$datafile_header
  3  where recover='YES'
  4  or (RECOVER IS NULL AND ERROR IS NOT NULL);

     FILE# STATUS
---------- -------
ERROR                                                             REC
----------------------------------------------------------------- ---
TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        15 OFFLINE
FILE NOT FOUND
```

It's the remnant of a tablespace which was used for some synchronization using streams.

How can I "delete" this file from oracle's memory?

Thanks

Comment: Can the entire tablespace be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shut the database down. Start it up again in mount mode:

```
connect / as sysdba;
startup mount;
```

Drop the datafile:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/full/path/of/file.dbf' OFFLINE DROP;
```

Open the DB:

```
alter database open;
```

Drop the tablespace:

```
DROP TABLESPACE <TS Name> INCLUDING CONTENTS;
```